# Optimizing signal voltage level for 5V device

Tags: signal, device

Are there any benefits associated with using lower signal voltages?

For example, if a 5V device has an input high voltage level minimum of 2V, would running input signals at, say 3.3 vs 4.5 or 5v have any significant effects?

I understand using lower ADC input voltages will reduce resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You won't save power on the 5V device and inputting closer to the minimum limit reduces your noise immunity so I'd say not.

However, if you are outputting 3V3 from a 3V3 device and that feeds a 5V device the benefit is that it will work albeit with reduced noise immunity.